Узнать fps каждого видеопотока
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html
Использую данную библиотеку...
Вопрос в том, как узнать FPS каждого видеопотока?
Есть битрейт, ширина и высота кадра, а так же продолжительность.
Возможности проигрывать видео и посчитывать кадры, нету. Возможно без это получить fps к каждому потоку?
Возможно что то не то делаю. Быть может в ffmpeg возможно добавить информацию по fps, которая будет отображаться в данном массиве?
this.dsh.getBitrateInfoListFor('video')


